# Split integer if double digit

Tags: list, python-2.7, int

I have a list of ints:

```
l1 = [8, 2, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 2]
```

How can I test for single digits? and if not single digits, split into single digits

```
for i in l1:
    if len(i) > 1:
        something
```

So new list would be:

```
l1 = [8, 2, 2, 6, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a string:

```
list(''.join(map(str, l1)))
```

It converts the numbers to strings, concatenates them all, then gets a list of the characters.

```
>>> l1 = [8, 2, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 2]
>>> list(''.join(map(str, l1)))
['8', '2', '2', '6', '1', '0', '1', '4', '1', '8', '2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a generator:

```
def split_digits(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        for digit in str(number):
            yield int(digit)

print list(split_digits([8, 2, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert every element to a string and then add each character

```
l1 = [8, 2, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 2]
l2 = []

for i in l1:
    s = str(i)

    for digit in s:
        l2.append(int(digit))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this, without using strings:

```
def convert(my_list):
    new_list = []
    for ele in my_list:
        new_list.extend(split(ele))
    return new_list

def split(x):
    if x == 0:
        return [0]
    result = []
    while x:
        result.append(x % 10)
    x /= 10
return result[::-1]
```

Result:

```
>>> convert(l1)
[8, 2, 2, 6, 1, 0, 1, 4, 1, 8, 2]
>>> convert([133, 34, 0, 44])
[1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 0, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, num in enumerate(nums):
    nums[i:i+1] = [int(d) for d in str(num)]
```